# Java XMLRPC client for Drupal6/Services 2.4 throws XmlRpcClientException

Tags: drupal, xml-rpc

I've built a Java client to connect to a Drupal6 service based on the Apache XmlRpcClient, but it keeps throwing the following exception:
    org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientException: Failed to parse server's response: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
I've checked request & response using Wireshark, and they seem fine content-wise.
Googling for this exception reveals there may be some whitespace in front of the XML header - but I'm not explicitly building the messages.
Any ideas how to resolve this problem?

Thanks

Frederik

Answer (score 0):

In the end I rebuilt the entire project using a custom XmlRpcCommonsTransportFactory (commons httpclient 3.1), and things started to work automagically...